# How to make alternative screen layout based on px?

Tags: android, layout

I got two devices that must use different layouts.

1st - 800x480px

2nd - 1280x720px

The system takes the layout if I use `layout-normal` folder but it affects both devices.

What qualifiers do I need to use to make the system use two different layout folders?

Answer (score 0):

When you create new layout, you can specify qualifiers to target specific needs. In your case, you can use the **Smalless Screen Width** qualifiers and set to 480dp for 1st layout and 720dp to 2nd

Comment: so I need 3 folders ```layout``` ```layout-normal``` ```layout-large```?

Comment: if you don't support the `layout` you can remove that folder. Android will decide which layout folder to use at runtime. Remember that if it does not find layout "below" your definition (ex: you support device with height less than 480 and you don't include `layout`), the app crashes.

Comment: No Large folder does not catch up by android for this type of dimens

Comment: I have edited my answer, that was my mistake about the size qualifier. You can refer to the [doc](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes#TaskUseSWQuali) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to make to folders

1st - minimum 320dp

2nd - minimum 360dp